# Why I can't retrive "likes_count" if I have "friends_likes" permissions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

This:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, likes_count FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
ORDER BY likes_count ASC
```

I'm using the Graph Explorer. My access token has **"friends_likes"** and "user_likes" enabled.

However, that query for the active logged in user (me) works.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, likes_count FROM user WHERE uid=me()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, likes_count FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
ORDER BY likes_count DESC
```

works perfectly fine for me. Please note that users have the possibility to deactivate the access to their data for apps their friends are using. That's why you'll see for some of your friends `null` as result value!

Comment: It's fixed. I don't know why. I guess the access token wasn't refreshed totally when I added "friends_likes" permissions.